# WPF application with SQL Server database

Tags: wpf, sql-server

I'm trying to make a WPF application with a SQL Server database,

First I created a database with SQL Server Management Studio, then I created a WPF application with the `./Express` database and that worked fine but if I run this on another PC he can't find my database ofc.

How can I fix this so the database is local and can run on all PC's?

Thx

Comment: Other PC has Sql Server installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other PC doesn't have a local database. You must either use a central database or create one on the other PC. If you want all instances of the application to use the same central database, change the connection string to contain `your-pc/Express` instead of `./Express` where "your-pc" is the name of your machine.

Comment: can I convert the Express database to a local database?

Comment: no, the other pc dosn't have SQL server installed , is it still posible if i convetert it to a local database then?